# Symfony service exists in dev environment and doesn't exist in prod environment

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have installed a brand new Symfony 2.5 on my production server to run some command line tasks (cron jobs based on symfony commands).

Whenever I run my command with no env argument or with --env=dev everything runs as expected. When I switch to prod environment by providing --env=prod I get this error message:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
You have requested a non-existent service "cache".
```

The only cause I can come up with is the Doctrine in memory cache I use to cache certain things during execution:

config.yml

```
services:
    cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: did you try php app/console cache:clear --env=prod?

Comment: I remember, I did that a few times before, but last one did the trick. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: please remove the question then :)

Comment: @nifr I see a value in the question and response that can save someone  an hour or two. I hope you are not concerned about disk space :)

Comment: @hserge it actually did :) thx